# Entity type 'ApexClass' is not available in this organization

Tags: deployment, migration-tool, ant

During the retrieve step (trying to retrieve the code) while trying to deploy the code in the target environment I get the following error:

> Retrieve warnings (1): [sf:retrieve] package.xml - Entity type
>   'ApexClass' is not available in this organization

In the **package.xml**, I have provided the ApexClass metadata type. Btw, I get this error in a certain org but dont get this in other orgs while trying to retrieve using the migration toolkit.

Comment: This was working 2 days back and noticing this error only recently. We use the ant migration toolkit along with our CI setup with Jenkins

Answer (score 7):

This could be a profile issue.  Make sure your user's Profile has the "Author Apex" permission.

Comment: This was my issue when trying to retrieve metadata from our prod org using the Force Migration Tool. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Not all orgs can use ApexClass. You need at least enterprise edition to use Apex Code. If the target org should be capable of housing code, it could be a glitch. In that case, contact support. They can fix this error.