# Few classes of managed package are not available to use in Subscriber org - Author Apex issue

Tags: apex, managed-package

Few classes of my managed package are not available to use in Subscriber org.(Visualforce page which are using these classes are not working). 
When "Author Apex" permission is granted on profile in Subscriber org, then those apex class and vf page are working.
This is happening in few subscriber only.
I couldn't find any thing for this strange issue as author Apex permission is required for create/edit apex class or if class is used by any API.
Please help me if any clue?
User don't want to give "Author Apex" permission to use a class.

Comment: What are these Apex classes doing? Is it anything that might require the "Author Apex" permission? I can't find anything outside [ApexClass](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/139080/102), [ConnectionParams](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_DataSource_ConnectionParams.htm), and [maybe the Apex Metadata API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/195178/102) with such a requirement.

Comment: Hello Daniel, There is nothing in these class which ask "Author Apex" permission. The page is used to show some custom object's record on  vf page.  There are also similar page and class which are working properly.

Answer (score 1):

There are two permissions necessary for a managed package. First, if not using a Site license, the user must be given a license to use your package. Second, the user must have permission to use the page or class, either via their Profile or a Permission Set. It's recommended that ISVs include Permission Sets so that subscribers can easily add all the required permissions to multiple users with ease.

So, for those users that you're experiencing trouble with, make sure they have the package enabled for their user account, and check their Profile to make sure they have access to the components they are trying to access, *or* make sure they have a Permission Set assigned to them that contains the relevant permissions.

Comment: Thanks for response. The user has licence assigned and he is also able to use the app. This issue occurred only for few apex classes( say 3 or 4 out of 100 class) .
If we give apex author permission then user are able to use these class.

One more thing: These classes are also not available during assign Apex classes on profile. 
After "Author Apex" permission on profile, these classes are available for assign on profile or remove assignment from profile.

Comment: @OmPrakash That seems odd. You might want to file a case with support if you have Developer Support.

Comment: I have raised a case and awaiting updated response. I will update here if anything.